# How to create new polynomial transformation variables that have their own names

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

I would like to add new variables that will have polynomial transformation based on the continuous variables that I have. I know how to do it manually `(dat$balls_poly<-poly(dat$balls,2)` but how can I do it for 100+ variables?

```
dat <- read.table(text = " category balls sticks shirts
                   yes        3        9         7
                   no         3        8         4
                   no         1        2         8
                   yes        1        2         3
                   yes        1        8         3
                   no         6        1         2
                   yes        6        7         1
                   no         6        1         5
                   yes        5        9         7
                   no         3        8         7
                   no         4        2         7
                   yes        1        2         3
                   yes        7        6         3
                   no         6        1         1
                   yes        6        3         9
                   no         6        1         1   ",header = TRUE)
```

EDIT:
I applied this line of code:

```
dat[,paste0("poly_",1:poly_order)] <- stats::poly(dat$balls, poly_order)
```

and got this output:

```
 dat
   category balls sticks shirts       poly_1      poly_2
1       yes     3      9      7 -0.124409488 -0.33739571
2        no     3      8      4 -0.124409488 -0.33739571
3        no     1      2      8 -0.358592053  0.22632756
4       yes     1      2      3 -0.358592053  0.22632756
5       yes     1      8      3 -0.358592053  0.22632756
6        no     6      1      2  0.226864360  0.03981688
7       yes     6      7      1  0.226864360  0.03981688
8        no     6      1      5  0.226864360  0.03981688
9       yes     5      9      7  0.109773077 -0.24896031
10       no     3      8      7 -0.124409488 -0.33739571
11       no     4      2      7 -0.007318205 -0.37469784
12      yes     1      2      3 -0.358592053  0.22632756
13      yes     7      6      3  0.343955643  0.49163375
14       no     6      1      1  0.226864360  0.03981688
15      yes     6      3      9  0.226864360  0.03981688
16       no     6      1      1  0.226864360  0.03981688
```

I wonder If I can get this output (showing only first row for simplicity of display):

```
 dat
   category balls sticks shirts       poly_balls      poly_stics poly_shirts
1       yes     3      9      7         9                 81        49
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's how to do it:

First type in the order of your polynomial:

```
poly_order <- 2
```

Then assign the new columns using `[` rather than `$`. Because `paste0` is vectorized, it will add as many columns as you have polynomials.

```
dat[,paste0("poly_",1:poly_order)] <- stats::poly(dat$balls, poly_order)
```

Comment: Thanks @Matt74, Is there a possibility to add the old name as part of the new data frame? for example: instead poly_1 to balls_1 ?

Comment: yes, see where it says `"poly_"` - that's a string variable that can be replaced by "balls_"

Comment: I meant If I can do it automatically that each new variable will get the old variable name that is related to it with the addition of "poly_" at the beginning of each one?

Comment: Also, can you please explain more about "stats::poly(dat$balls, poly_order)", How can it be applied to all columns if there is a direct phrase like : "dat$balls".Thanks @Matt74

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "applied to all columns", but in the `poly()` function, you can use the same `[` notation, as follows:  `myvar <- "balls"; stats::poly(dat[,myvar], poly_order)`

Comment: @2Matt74, I edited my q with desired output so my q will be more clear.Thanks.